# Floyd Warshall reconstruct path

Tags: graph, path

I want to reconstruct the path from source to destination vertex in this graph problem.

How can I store the path, and how can I retrieve it after I have found the minimal cost from s to d?

Please help me to find a simple answer?

For example at the point,

```
adjmat[i][j] = Math.min(adjMat[i][j],adjMat[i][k]+adjMat[k][j]);
```

I need to add a path and I need to retrieve it.

Comment: What have you done so far? Do you have any code? Can you be any more specific?

Answer (score 4):

The Wikipedia article about the [Floyd-Warshall algorithm](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Floyd%E2%80%93Warshall_algorithm) provides an [explanation and pseudocode](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Floyd%E2%80%93Warshall_algorithm#Path_reconstruction) for your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use optimal matrix with Floyd-Warshall Algorithm to reconstruct path. It construct path simulatneously.
Refer to Introduction to graph theory- by Narsingh Deo for actual algorithm